# How to fetch previous record in arraylist in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, cursor

I'm making an quiz app in which there are two buttons i.e next and previous for fetching next and prev question. I'm able to fetch the next question but didn't able to fetch previous question. Done lots of google and R&D regarding this but didn't get any right solution.

Here is my code:

Database:

```
  public List<NotificationListItem> getNQuestions(String tid) {
    List<NotificationListItem> quest = new ArrayList<NotificationListItem>();

    openToRead();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM quiz_list"+ " where tid = ?", new String[] { tid});
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NotificationListItem item = new NotificationListItem();
            int id=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_QID);
            int answer=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_ANSWER);
            int testid=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_TESTID);
            int questions=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_QUES);
            int option1=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_OP1);
            int option2=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_OP2);
            int option3=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_OP3);
            int option4=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_OP4);
            int option5=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_OP5);
            int anscount=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_ANSC);
            int totalchoice=cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizTable.KEY_TC);

            item.qID=cursor.getInt(id);
            item.answer=cursor.getString(answer);
            item.testID=cursor.getString(testid);
            item.questions=cursor.getString(questions);
            item.option1=cursor.getString(option1);
            item.option2=cursor.getString(option2);
            item.option3=cursor.getString(option3);
            item.option4=cursor.getString(option4);
            item.option5=cursor.getString(option5);
            item.anscount=cursor.getString(anscount);
            item.tc=cursor.getString(totalchoice);
            quest.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return quest list
    return quest;
}
```

QuizActivity:

```
    NotificationListItem Nitem;
    List<NotificationListItem> Nquest;

    nextBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtIV);
    prevBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevIV);
    prevBT.setEnabled(false);

    quizTable = new QuizTable(this);
    quizTable.openToRead();
    quizTable.openToWrite();

    Nquest=quizTable.getNQuestions(testID);
    Nitem=Nquest.get(questionid);

    setQuestionView();

    nextBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resultquiz();
           if(qID<Nquest.size()){
                Nitem=Nquest.get(qID);
                prevBT.setEnabled(true);  
                setQuestionView();
                qID++;
            }  
           else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivityB.this, TestAnalysisActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("totalquestion",qs);
                intent.putExtra("testtime",time);
                intent.putExtra("testname", testName);
                intent.putExtra("testID", testID);
                intent.putExtra("currentDateandTime", date);
                intent.putExtra("totalattemp",totalattempt);
                intent.putExtra("totalMarks", totalMarks);
                intent.putExtra("subject", subject);
                intent.putExtra("score", finalscore);
                intent.putExtra("percentage", percentage);
                intent.putExtra("timecounter", timeCounterFinish);
                intent.putExtra("correctAns", cAns);
                intent.putExtra("negativeAns", nAns);
                intent.putExtra("comments", comments);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
           }}
    });

    prevBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(qID>0){

                    Pitem=Pquest.get(qID);
                    setQuestionView();  
                    qID--;   
            }}
    });

  private void setQuestionView()
  {
    txtQuestion.setText(Nitem.getquestions());

      op1=(Nitem.getOption1());
      op2=(Nitem.getOption2());
      op3=(Nitem.getOption3());
      op4=(Nitem.getOption4());
      op5=(Nitem.getOption5());
      ans=(Nitem.getAnswer());
      ansc=Nitem.getAnscount();
      tc=(Nitem.getTc());
      questionid=(Nitem.getqID());
      totalchoice=Integer.parseInt(tc);
      anscount=Integer.parseInt(ansc);
      System.out.println("QUESTIONID="+questionid);
      System.out.println("ANSWER="+ans);

      if(anscount==1)
        {
        rc.removeAllViews();
        addRadioButtons();
        }
        else if(anscount>1)
        {
        rc.removeAllViews();
        addCheckButtons();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think this is the problem Pitem=Pquest.get(qID); try Pitem=Pquest.get(qID-1);

Comment: why you get your data in pre from `Pquest` and in next from `Nquest`? i think you should get from one list, and instead of qId you need use `qId-2` , qId is next question, `qId-1` is current question so you need use `qId-2` , and increment `qId` like next button after your logic

Comment: why you are not use same list i.e. Nquest for previous and next operation. change this line  Pitem=Pquest.get(qID); to  Pitem=Nquest.get(qID); in previous click and test

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i used your code and it works but when i reaches the last qstn then there is an error as ARRAY OUTOFBOUND INDEX. so help me regarding this.

Comment: you need check your index that must be between `0` and `list.size()-1`, if is bigger that or less than this threshold you must do some other thing

Comment: thank you... now problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could create youself an `int` variable which you should increment or decrement, and fetch desired record from ArrayList using `list.get(variable)`.

Comment: i have already done this and fetching the next question with increment(qID++) but it didn't work right in decrement(qID--)

Comment: Did u use the right increment/decrement? For example var++ increases after use while ++var before use